# Paths property in tsconfig doesn't work

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, transpiler

I'm trying to use paths property in my tsconfig.json file.

It makes the build work perfectly but execution of generated js is failing.

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "paths": {
            "core/*": [
                "core/*"
            ]
        },
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

src/core/service.ts:

```
export class Service {
    public static log(message: string) {
        console.log('message', message);
    }
}
```

src/core/index.ts:

```
export * from './service';
```

src/index.ts:

```
import { Service } from 'core';

Service.log('test');
```

The build is working perfectly

But running dist\index.js I obtain:

**Error: Cannot find module 'core'**

Am I doing something wrong?

I made a repo to illustrate this:
https://github.com/BUONJG/typescript-paths.git

Many thanks for your support,

Jean-Guy

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Were you ever able to figure it out?